# How to add zoom feature to a edit control?

Tags: windows, user-interface, zooming

I need to add zoom feature, like zoom web page in firefox, chrome, or zoom edit page in word, to a edit control which wrote by our company. The edit control contains text, draw-text, draw-images.

So I come up with a solution, modify all lines which are related to calculate position, size, font size with an percentage factor.

But I think I need some directions or samples to follow, could you give me some references or point me which source file does this zoom/scale lies in firefox/chrome.

Sorry for my English, long time no say and Thanks for you attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually zoom feature in firefox/chrome etc use the zoom matrix in the theory of computer graphics.

Normally 2d libraries such as cairo(firefox etc), skia(chrome etc) is based on homogeneous matrix, which is the same as other 3d libraries(opengl/directx). Setting a zoom matrix to the canvas of these libraries and everything is zoomed.

This is how things work out.